# Using Survey123 For Asset Inspection through Field Maps AND on a Webpage

Tags: assets, arcgis, inspection

We want to deploy a survey that can be accessed by members of the public in order to collect information on tide levels at 10 pre-determined sites. I have a feature class with the 10 points (sites), and a related table with the questions to be filled by volunteers. These are linked (1:m) using the GlobalID of the 10 sites, and a GUID in the related table. For staff, we have been using Field Maps to simply go out to each site, click a point and fill out the related table (works great).

However, the majority of our volunteer base is not quite tech saavy, and are accustomed to filling out forms in these types of situations. Ideally I would like to embed a survey on our website where they can choose the site (either from a dropdown menu or by clicking a point on a map) and then fill out all the relevant information.

I began setting this up using Survey123 and although filling out surveys for pre-determined locations works ok with the Survey123 app (using the Inbox feature), the web app version is giving me a lot of trouble. Every entry on the web-app creates a new site in the parent layer (with a new GlobalID). I understand the inbox feature cannot be used in the web app. How can I configure my xls in Survey123 Connect such that entries on the webpage add new records (inspections) to the related table without adding new points to the sites (parent layer)?